# Use Nest in a recurrence function

Tags: functions, iteration

I have following recurrence function:

```
al0[k_, ee_] := (k d[k, ee] + (k + 1) d[k + 1, ee]) (-1)^k ;
al1[k_, ee_] := 
  al0[k, ee] - (k + 1)/(2 k + 3) al0[k + 1, ee] - k/(2 k - 1) al0[k - 1, ee];
al2[k_, ee_] := 
  al1[k, ee] - (k + 1)/(2 k + 3) al1[k + 1, ee] - k/(2 k - 1) al1[k - 1, ee];
al3[k_, ee_] := 
  al2[k, ee] - (k + 1)/(2 k + 3) al2[k + 1, ee] - k/(2 k - 1) al2[k - 1, ee];
```

Could I use Nest to make it simpler and faster? If not nest, anything else i can use?

Answer (score 5):

you can use memoization, which use more memory but gives you a faster answer

```
   al[0, k_, ee_] := 
  al[0, k, ee] = (k d[k, ee] + (k + 1) d[k + 1, ee]) (-1)^k;

al[i_, k_, ee_] := 
  al[i, k, ee] = 
   al[i - 1, k, ee] - (k + 1)/(2 k + 3) al[i - 1, k + 1, ee] - 
    k/(2 k - 1) al[i - 1, k - 1, ee];

al3[k, ee] == al[3, k, ee]
```

> True

i added a third index to control the number of iterations

Comment: @Edmund it should work now

Comment: I find that this behaves much better than `alNest` as it allows e.g. `al[22, .3, .7]`, assuming a numeric definition for `d` e.g. `d = Plus`.  `alNest` will choke attempting to making one huge Symbolic expression. ( @Edmund )

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes. It the symbolic expression does get complicated for small n.(+1)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Humm, on second thought would not `al` and `alNest` have equal performance on the first run since `al` is traversing the memoization from highest to lowest and needs the lower indices. Also, with `alNest` the result is a function in which `k` and `ee` are parameters.  Therefore, for any particular nesting `alNest` will be faster on the following runs since the function does not have to be rebuilt for new values of `k` and `ee` at that nesting level.

Comment: @Edmund Did you *try* to evaluate `alNest[22]`?  I think you'll find it's well beyond the capacity of the system.  On the other hand `al[22, .3, .7]` works just fine if we define `d = Plus` or some other numeric operator.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yeah. Tried it. Was not pretty. :-(

Comment: @Edmund Please understand that I am not disparaging your answer. It's a nice piece of coding and I voted for it.  I just thought it important to highlight the practical effect of expressing something more naturally written as a recursion (IMHO) in another style.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I appreciate the constructive critique. It's how we get better.

Answer (score 4):

You may use [`Nest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html) by returning a [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) for each nested level.

With `al0`as defined in OP

```
alNest[n_Integer?Positive] :=
 Nest[
  Function[{foo}, 
   Function[{k, ee}, 
    foo[k, ee] - (k + 1)/(2 k + 3) foo[k + 1, ee] - k/(2 k - 1) foo[k - 1, ee]
  ]],
  al0,
  n]
```

Then

```
opSol3 = al3[k, ee] // FullSimplify;
nestSol3 = alNest[3][k, ee] // FullSimplify;
opSol3 == nestSol3
```

> ```
> True
> ```

`alNest` returns the nested function. This can be saved to a variable for reuse (`nest3 = alNest[3];`) and used multiple times later on (`nest3[k, ee]`), or it can be used immediately as in the code snippet above.

Hope this helps.